# Вечерни(и/е) платья - как правильно?

Tags: орфография

Какую букву выбрать? Какое правило здесь действет?

Answer (score 2):

1. Платье (как**ое**?) вечерн**ее** (И. п. и В. п., ед. ч., ср. р.).
2. Платья (как**ие**?) вечерн**ие** (И. п. и В. п., мн. ч.).

Написание безударных окончаний прилагательных можно проверить постановкой вопроса *какой?* в нужном падеже:
платьев — как**их**? — вечерн**их**;
платьями — как**ими**? — вечерн**ими**.

Склонение прилагательного «вече́рний» (изменение по родам, числам и падежам) можно посмотреть [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9).